# Stop Event Propagation for Chrome Page Action

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am building a chrome extension with page action. When i click on the icon of page action, it triggers the click event but the click also opens up chrome's predictive service or suggestions. It happens because i have no way of stopping the the event propagation to address bar which in turn captures the click event and shows the predictive service.
I know users can disable the predictive service but thats not the solution. How can i make click event to stop the propagation or control that predictive service from my extension? chrome's onclick event handler only gets the tab but not the click event

```
function( tabs.Tab tab)
```

[image]

Comment: Cannot reproduce in Linux (38.0.2125.106 and 41.0.2221.0). How did you get the button to show when the "Press Tab to search ..." shows up?

Comment: That sounds like a bug. Check the [issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/list). @RobW That happens when you ad a site as a search engine.

Comment: @abraham I'm aware of that. I asked why the button showed up in the "Press Tab ..." area, *not* why the "Press tab ..." text shows up. If I add `example.com` as a search engine, create an extension with a page action, and start typing anything, the button disappears. When I press the button, then the omnibox is not focused (let alone the search predirection results), and the "Press Tab .." text does not even show up. I wonder which OS and Chrome version the OP is using.

Comment: I am on mac os (mavericks) , chrome version :38.0.2125.122

Comment: Yes if start typing , my extension button will disappear. But i am not typying anything, i just click on the extention button and all that appears on address bar.

Comment: @RizwanSharif I have verified that your bug exists on Mac, and opened a new bug report: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=435345.

Comment: @RobW , Thanks a lot. Hopefully we will see some fix for the issue.